# Different behaviors on Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I am creating a simulink library block. This block can have 3 different behaviors, one very fast (most common case by far) and the two others very slow. I first implemented it using a configurable subsystem but later on I changed it. The problem with this implementation is that, when compiled, only the selected user choice goes to the executable code.

I need a way to implement this block in a way that ...

1. The code generated must have all 3 options
2. If the user chooses the fast behavior, the performance should not be affected by the other 2 slow behaviors not selected

So far, my last approach is to use a if/else statement inside simulink, if a merge block (see picture)

[image]

My questions is:

1. Is it a naive implementation?
2. Is there a better way to do it using variant subsystems, or ANYTHING else?

Comment: This looks like the right way to go.

Comment: How do you get USER_CHOICE?

Comment: @Navan, USER_CHOICE is a manually configurable integer value that the end user can change during simulation.

Comment: If USER_CHOICE is from a constant source block with inf sample time in generated code non-hitting branches could get eliminated. Otherwise you will see those branches in code.